# Laravel download files

Tags: php, laravel, file, pdf, download

I would like for users to be able to download files in my Laravel application. I have many files inside a public folder, and every file belong to a post. For example, when an admin creates a new post and uploads a file (e.g., like an image in the post), the user can download that image/or pdf.

I've made a button so the user can download a file, but I get the error:

```
The file "/home/vagrant/Code/BDC/public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/1" does not exist
```

And this is my code, with a download button to do the "magic":

```
public function downloadAudiobook($id)
{
    try
    {
        if (Auth::user())
        {

            $audiobook = public_path('uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $id);
            return response()->download($audiobook);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('validate', 'Por favor inicia sesión para descargar este audiolibro');
        }
    }

    catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
    {
        Session::flash('flash_message', "Ha ocurrido un error procesando su solicitud, intente mas tarde.");
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I know, I pass the ID in the route where are the files, because, I don't know how do it.

And this is my route:

```
Route::get('audiobooks/download/{id}',['as' => 'audiobooks.download','uses' => 'AudiobookController@downloadAudiobook']);
```

Comment: maybe you forgot to append  file extension? i suppose your path should be something like `public_path('uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $id. '.pdf')`

Comment: I agree with @AndriyLozynskiy, try appending the file extension.

Comment: Yes, I do, but, the real problem is that Laravel give me a "file" that is a route of the file: "public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/1" until /audiobook_location/ it's well, but, where is "/1" need to have the name of the file, to download, so, the route have to be: "public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/*Name of the file.mp3" Do you understand me?

Comment: Which table are you store your file name like "test.mp3"?

Comment: The table is "audiobooks" and in this table save all the files of the information about post with the topic of audiobooks

Answer (score 1):

You should try this may be you understand my answer and its help for you:

```
public function downloadAudiobook($id)
{
  try
  {
    if (Auth::user())
    {
      //Your table where you store your filename and get your file like

      $resltFile = DB::table('yourTableName')->where('id',$id)->first();  


      $audiobook = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $resltFile->fileName;

      return response()->download($audiobook);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('validate', 'Por favor inicia sesión para descargar este audiolibro');
    }
  }

  catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
  {
    Session::flash('flash_message', "Ha ocurrido un error procesando su solicitud, intente mas tarde.");
    return redirect()->back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I change Somethings, and I got the next, first, change the route, so, this is the button to download: {{ route('audiobooks.download', $audiobooks->audiobook_location) }} Where, audiobook_location is the field of the database to save the route of: /uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/ and, change the controller for this: $audiobook = public_path('public/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $id. '.mp3'); but, I got this error: 
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException; and, when I click the button to download, redirect to a route with the path, and the name of the file, but not download

Comment: @CONFABDC Please put static file name of your mp3 file name with my answer instead of `$resltFile->fileName` and check work or not

Comment: I put the next -> $audiobook = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $resltFile->La noche boca arriba Cortazar Julio.mp3; where La noche boca arriba.mp3 is the name of the file saved in the public path, and I got this: 
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'noche' (T_STRING); I thinks that is because the file have spaces between the name; I changed to  $audiobook = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/' . $audiobook ->La noche boca arriba Cortazar Julio.mp3; and is the same; I really don't know what do

Comment: @CONFABDC Please rename `La noche boca arriba Cortazar Julio.mp3` TO `La_noche_boca_arriba_Cortazar_Julio.mp3` and check

Comment: I do it, and I got this: 
(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: resltFile
It's obviously that this variable didn't exist, how can change that?

Comment: @CONFABDC Dear $resltFile variable just for example

Comment: @CONFABDC Just put static file like test.mp3 name in audiobook_location folder and put this test.mp3 instead of $resltFile and check

Comment: Yeah, I do it, in the path have the name how you put, and do exactly the same, and I got the same error, even put a file with the name test.mp3, say variable undefined

Comment: @CONFABDC Are you put same like 
`$audiobook = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/test.mp3' ;` Please check

Comment: Well, I put exactly the same ($audiobook = public_path().'/uploads/audiobooks/audiobook_location/test.m‌​p3' ;" and download the file test.mp3